# vb.net Dictionary(Of String, Object) enum.getname()

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, enums

I am doing an VB.Net WinForm Application. It is a migration of C#.

In C# I have a variable defined like this.

```cs
 private static Dictionary<string, ExportFormatType> dicExtensiones =
            new Dictionary<string, ExportFormatType> {
                        {".pdf", ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat},
                        {".doc", ExportFormatType.WordForWindows},
                        {".xls", ExportFormatType.Excel},
                        {".rtf", ExportFormatType.RichText},
                        {".html", ExportFormatType.HTML40},
                        {".txt", ExportFormatType.Text}
                   };
```

And i migrated to this..

```vb
   Private Shared dicExtensiones = New Dictionary(Of String, ExportFormatType) From
                            {{".pdf", ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat},
                             {".doc", ExportFormatType.WordForWindows},
                             {".xls", ExportFormatType.Excel},
                             {".rtf", ExportFormatType.RichText},
                             {".html", ExportFormatType.HTML40},
                             {".txt", ExportFormatType.Text}}
```

Now I need to Loop through all ítems and get each value...

In C# is like this.

```cs
 List<String> lista = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in dicExtensiones)
            {
                lista.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(ExportFormatType), item.Value));
                lista.Add("*" + item.Key);
            }
```

The problem i have is that I do know how to migrate

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(ExportFormatType), item.Value);
```

to VB.Net, because `Enum.GetName` does not exists in VB.Net

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can be like below in VB

```
Dim lista As List(Of [String]) = New List(Of String)()

For Each item As var In dicExtensiones
    lista.Add([Enum].GetName(GetType(ExportFormatType), item.Value))
    lista.Add("*" + item.Key)
Next
```

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`... On another note `VB` uses `&` for string concatenation, not `+`... Also what is `var`type, this answer is wrong all completely...

Answer (score 4):

In VB, `Enum` is a keyword, as well as a class name, so you need to escape it in your code.  The escaping syntax is similar to SQL:

```
[Enum].GetName
```

By escaping it, you're telling the compiler that you are referring to the identifier by that name rather than the keyword.  For instance, you might also need to escape your own class or variable names on occasion:

```
Dim [property] As String = "belt, wallet with $50, casio watch"
```

or

```
Public Class [Class]
    Public Property Teacher As String
    Public Property Students As List(Of Student)
End Class
```

Though, in most cases it's preferable to just avoid it by thinking of a different name to use.